# Save user created variables in database with user session ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, session-variables

I am building an application that uses web forms authentication and allows users to log on and create a list of people from a sql database. The users can create the list by selecting from multiple dropdown menus.  The code in the back end then create a string from the selected dropdowns that gets passes into the sql Data source as a select statement.  I need to find a way for the users to save the sql string variable that gets created, so when they log in again they can view their saved lists.  My idea was to get the session variable or user ID and insert it into the data base along with the variable, but I cannot figure out the best way to do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What was wrong with your approach?

Comment: If you create a variable it has to have an owner, obviously. There's nothing wrong to identify the a variables owner through his ID.

Comment: Session Variable: No, is dynamically generated for each User Request when browser is closed and reopened. User ID is a good idea, where is the problem? You don't know the user id? You can save it after login in your Session and use it when required. (es. var userId = Session["UserId"];)

Comment: Where would I put this code? Thanks

Comment: And are you attempting to store it as some sort of concatenated string?  There are issues with that approach - you may want to consider creating tables for some collections of entities, and you may need (although I hope not) some sort of EAV.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older post, but you don't seem to have found a satisfactory answer.  Additionally, I cannot make comments to the discussion thread, so I have to submit my idea in this way.

Have you considered storing the variables in XML, and saving the XML to a column in the database (such as a user_pref table)?

When your database authenticates the user, I presume you have a stored proc performing part of the action.  Why not have that stored proc pull the XML and pass it along to the web form for parsing?  XML is widely supported in web interfaces, so this could be a fairly easy solution to implement.